# Integrate complex function

Tags: integration, complex-numbers

In a physics textbook I am working with, the following integral is caluclated:

> Define the complex elastic modulus as $\overline{M} = M_1 + i M_2$ where $\overline{M}$ is a function of the angular frequency $\overline{M}(\omega)$.  If $\epsilon = \epsilon_0 e^{i \omega t}$ and $\sigma = \overline{M} \epsilon$, the energy disspated in one cycle is
>
> $$\Delta W = \int_{\omega t = 0}^{2 \pi} \sigma d \epsilon = \pi M_2 \epsilon_{0}^{2}$$

I don't quite understand how this integral is calculated.  When I try to do this by myself I get:

$$\Delta W = \int_{\omega t = 0}^{2 \pi} \sigma d \epsilon = \int_{\omega t = 0}^{2 \pi} \overline{M} \epsilon d \epsilon = \left[\frac{\overline{M} \epsilon^2}{2} \right]_{\omega t = 0}^{2 \pi}$$

$$= \frac{\overline{M} (2 \pi)^2}{2} - \frac{\overline{M} \epsilon_0 ^{2}}{2} = 2 \pi^2 \overline{M} - \frac{\overline{M} \epsilon_0 ^{2}}{2}$$

This is as far as I get.  I don't see how we can get the final result by plugging in $\overline{M} = M_1 + i M_2$, so obviously I'm doing something wrong.  If anyone can show me how to actually compute this integral, I would be really grateful!

Comment: It's even worse... Note that when $\omega t=0$ or $2\pi$, we have $\epsilon=\epsilon_0$, thus the difference is actually $0$. Are you sure that $\overline{M}$ is constant along the integration?

Comment: Well, this is exactly how this is presented in the book.  No more information is given.  But for some reason in the upper limit of integration it only says $2 \pi$ and not $\omega t = 2 \pi$.  I thought this could mean something.

Comment: This is one of the times where physicists abuse of notation gets irritating. It says $\overline{M}$ is a function of $\omega$ but then this means that we have to integrate it alongside $e^{i \omega t}$. What subject is this? Perhaps you could ask on Physics.SE for help on understanding what's going on (not on the math).

Comment: Yes, I thought this notation was confusing as heck also.  This is a course in rock physics I'm going to take this fall, and I started reading through the assigned readings to give myself a head start.  I will either ask on a physics forum, or ask on my professor.  Good to know I'm not the only one confused (I have a background in mathematics).